# The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds,angular ver 13 & netCore ver -3.1.5

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, package.json, timeoutexception

**[There are several similar questions on this topic but none of the worked for me]**

I added ClientApp to my existing .netcore application. Angular version is 13.0.0 and .net core version is 3.1.5. When I tried to run the clientapp in browser got this issue

> TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds

The workarounds I tried so far :

**Startup.cs** - in configure method

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
```

used this in Startup.cs and got this error

> Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:4200/ClientApp, because the request to the proxy target failed. Check that the proxy target server is running and accepting requests to http://localhost:4200/. The underlying exception message was 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'.Check the InnerException for more details.

then changed it to:

```
 app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                 spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                //spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
```

But this did not help.
**Startup.cs** - in congigureServices method

```
 services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";
            }
            else
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
            }
        });
```

**package.json:**

```
  "start": "echo Starting... && ng serve",
```

but this only worked if I externally run ng serve on clienapp using cmd and then run the application. If I directly run the application it's not working.

**angular.json**

changed output path:

```
"outputPath": "../wwwroot",
```

Can anyone please help me understand what could be the issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi @Priya, what's the error message if you comment this line: `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");` ?

Comment: @Rena I am getting the same timeout issue again if I remove it